# Setting ExtendedProperties related to a Room

Tags: c#, .net, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am very new to EWS and Exchange in general, so not really sure what is the best approach.

**Background**

I am trying to set configuration information about a room. I was hoping that the EWS API provided me with a `Room` object that I can add `ExtendedProperties` on, however, it appears that rooms are just an email address.

I then saw that each room had a `CalendarFolder` associated with it, so I am now trying to set the room configuration in the `CalendarFolder`, which is what the original question below refers to.

**Original Question**

I am trying to do a simple update of a `CalendarFolder` using:

```
var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(roomEmail.Address));
var myCalendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, folderId, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

myCalendar.DisplayName += "Updated";
myCalendar.Update();
```

However, when I call `.Update()` I get "*The folder save operation failed due to invalid property values.*"

I believe that the problem might have something to do with `myCalendar` not having all of the properties that the calendar folder has on the server. So when I update the object it is only sending a partial object which is causing validation errors.

How would I go about updating a `CalendarFolder`?

**After further research**

I also stumbled across the following, which does work:

```
FindFoldersResults root = service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new FolderView(500));

foreach (var folder in root.Folders)
{
     folder.DisplayName = "confRoom1";
     folder.Update();
}
```

I'm sure there is a difference between the two approaches, but I don't understand the differences between the folder that I get using the different query methods:

```
new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(roomEmail.Address));
var myCalendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, folderId, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

and

```
service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new FolderView(500));
```

Which approach would give me the correct `CalendarFolder` where I can set the `ExtendedProperties` for the room?

Comment: Have you any new insights? Did one of the proposed answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > I'm sure there is a difference between the two approaches, but I don't understand the differences between the folder that I get using the different query methods:
> >
> > new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new Mailbox(roomEmail.Address));
> >     var myCalendar = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, folderId, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
> >     and
> >
> > service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, new FolderView(500));

The First binds to the default calendar folder in a Mailbox and the second get the subfolders within the Default calendar folder. You can rename the subfolders within the default calendar folder because they are user created. You cannot rename the Default calendar folder in a Mailbox because its a special folder. If you want to set a Extended property (which you can do on a special folder then it easy just define it and set it) eg

```
ExtendedPropertyDefinition MyCustomProp = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.PublicStrings, "MyCustomProp", MapiPropertyType.String);

CalendarFolder CalendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service,new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "user@domain.com"));
CalendarFolder.SetExtendedProperty(MyCustomProp, "My Value");
CalendarFolder.Update();
```

What you want to get that value you must define a propertySet that tells exchange to return that value when you either Bind or use FindItems (Exchange will not return your property by default) eg

```
PropertySet MyPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
MyPropSet.Add(MyCustomProp);
CalendarFolder = CalendarFolder.Bind(service, new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "mailbox@domain.com"),MyPropSet);
Object PropValue = null;
if (CalendarFolder.TryGetProperty(MyCustomProp, out PropValue)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(PropValue);
}
```

Comment: I've added explanation of what I am trying to accomplish.